# Efficient way for in between merge of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, performance, html5-canvas

I have single channel pixel data in plain DataView format. So the size of the DataView is width*height. For rendering a bitmap from that data, I need to get 4-channel data if I'm right. My current test/naive implementation is like this.

```js
const data = new Uint8ClampedArray(data);
const expanded = new Uint8ClampedArray(width * height * 4);
data.forEach((v, i) => {
 expanded[i * 4] = v;
 expanded[i * 4 + 1] = v;
 expanded[i * 4 + 2] = v;
 expanded[i * 4 + 3] = 255;
});
```

But that's obviously not performant. On 12 megapixel data, this takes something like 300ms. Is there a more efficient way to do a merge like this?

Or even better as a side question: Can I draw single channel bitmap on img tag or canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can boost the performance by filling your target array with 32 bit instead of 8 bit unsigned integers. In this case the 32 bit value holds the r, g, b and alpha value which you can send using a single instruction.

To better understand let's look at an example. Say we have the color `#4080c4` with full alpha `ff`. On a **little-endian** processor architecture this corresponds to:

```
0xffc48040 == 4291067968

Alpha==0xff==255

Blue==0xc4==196

Green=0x80==128

Red==0x40==64
```

So the 8 bit unsigned integer values are 255, 64, 128 and 196 respectively. To make a 32 bit unsigned integer out of this 4 individual values we need to use `bit-shifting`.

If we look back at the hexadecimal number - `0xffc48040` - in a naive way, we can see that the `ff` alpha value is at the left. That means there are 24 bits before which in turn means that `ff` has to be shifted 24 bits to the left. If we apply the same logic to the remaining three values we end up with this:

```
let UI32LE = (Alpha << 24) | (Blue << 16) | (Green << 8) | Red;
```

The `<<` is JavaScript's bitshift operator.

Please note that the order of the bits is important! As I mentioned, the above applies to little-endian. If it's a `big-endian` architecture the order is different:

```
let UI32BE = (Red << 24) | (Green << 16) | (Blue << 8) | Alpha;
```

Now if we take this technique and use it on something close to your use case we end up with this:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let width = canvas.width;
let height = canvas.height;
let dummyData = [];
for (let a = 0; a < width * height; a++) {
  dummyData.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 255));
}
const data = new Uint8ClampedArray(dummyData);

let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(width * height * 4);
let dataView = new Uint32Array(buffer);
let expanded = new Uint8ClampedArray(buffer);

data.forEach((v, i) => {
  dataView[i] = (255 << 24) | (v << 16) | (v << 8) | v;
});

let imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
imageData.data.set(expanded);

context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```